# Pandas HDFStore change format of stored dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

Suppose we are using `pandas.HDFStore` for storing df. And let it storing format be `table`. So we can [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#querying) subframes, make some wrangling, [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#table-format) more data into df (suppose we are working with streaming data), etc.

But once we finished processing data (in case of streaming - for example we have processed all the data for the past year) we may want this data become 'solid' i.e. no queries/appends more needed (we already done with it). And at the same time we may want to read full `df` from `HDFStore` back for example to visualize the processed results. In this case `fixed` format is best. Because it takes less place on disk, is much more faster to read the whole.

So to the matter - is there the way to perform **on_disk** change format of stored dataframe from `table` to `fixed`(maybe delete all 'indexes' or somewhat like this)?

Why on-disk? Because of RAM of course. During appending our `df` might become really *big* so our RAM is enough only for reading df and make some simple plot or calc some stats and we cannot afford it to even read `df` from the store in `table` format:

```py
size_mult = 7
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**size_mult, 10),
                  columns = list('abcdefghik'))
print('df size is %d MiB' % (df.memory_usage().sum()//1024**2))

with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    %memit store.put('df', df, 't', data_columns=['a','b','c'])
    %memit store.select('df')
    store.remove('df')

del df
_ = gc.collect()
```

Takes a lot excessive memory:

```py
df size is 762 MiB
peak memory: 2375.16 MiB, increment: 1335.83 MiB
peak memory: 4217.48 MiB, increment: 3088.03 MiB
```

---

I think here it is worthy to take a second and embrace 'funny' note - with df size 760 MiB one need 4200 MiB (i.e. in about ***6 times*** more than the initial df size) in order to simply read dataframe from `HDFStore` if format is `table` and 3 data columns are specified.

---

But if somehow managed to change format on disk to `fixed` situation becomes more acceptable:

```py
size_mult = 7
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**size_mult, 10),
                  columns = list('abcdefghik'))
print('df size is %d MiB' % (df.memory_usage().sum()//1024**2))

with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    %memit store.put('df', df, 'f')
    %memit store.select('df')
    store.remove('df')

del df
_ = gc.collect()
```

```py
df size is 762 MiB
peak memory: 1001.88 MiB, increment: 76.30 MiB
peak memory: 1745.78 MiB, increment: 743.89 MiB
```